# Spring Cloud Stream - Functions - How to manually acknowledge rabbitmq message?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm using a spring cloud stream with rabbitbinder.

Using a @StreamListener, I could manually acknowledge rabbitmq messages by having Channel and deliveryTag injected into the method as follows:

```java
 @StreamListener(target = MySink.INPUT1)
 public void listenForInput1(Message<String> message,
      @Header(AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL) Channel channel,
      @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) Long deliveryTag) throws IOException {

    log.info(" received new message [" + message.toString() + "] ");
    channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false);
 }
```

I am now trying to achieve the same using functions:

```java
 @Bean
 public Consumer<Message<String>> sink1() {
    return message -> {
      System.out.println("******************");
      System.out.println("At Sink1");
      System.out.println("******************");
      System.out.println("Received message " + message.getPayload());
    };
  }
```

How do I get the Channel object in here so that I can acknowledge it with the deliveryTag?
I am able to get the delivery tag form headers. However, I am unable to get the channel Object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to figure it out:

```
  @Bean
  public Consumer<Message<String>> sink1() {
    return message -> {
      System.out.println("******************");
      System.out.println("At Sink1");
      System.out.println("******************");
      System.out.println("Received message " + message.getPayload());

      Channel channel = message.getHeaders().get(AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL, Channel.class);
      Long deliveryTag = message.getHeaders().get(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG, Long.class);

      try {
        channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    };
  }
```

Comment: I tried that, i can only do that after 2 days :) so i will be able to accept it tomorrow.