# Manual ack after message send with Spring Cloud Stream + RabbitMQ (Functional)

Tags: spring, kotlin, rabbitmq, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

[I found how to do manual ack with functional way.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61204338/spring-cloud-stream-functions-how-to-manually-acknowledge-rabbitmq-message)

However, this does not explain how to do manual ack sending **after** messages.
If there is a networking error between the ack and the sending of the message, I think the message will be lost.
I don't want to lose message.

Versions

- Spring boot : 2.7.1
- Spring Cloud : 3.2.4

This is my current code

```kotlin
@Controller
class MyFunction(private val myService: MyService) {
    private val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()

    init {
        objectMapper.registerKotlinModule()
    }
    
    @Bean
    fun function(): (Message<ByteArray>) -> Message<MyResponse> = {
        val channel = it.headers.get(AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL, Channel::class.java)!!
        val deliveryTag = it.headers.get(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG, java.lang.Long::class.java)!!.toLong()
        
        val request = objectMapper.readValue(it.payload, MyRequest::class.java)
        
        try {
            val response = myService.process(request)
            
            channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false)
            // I think it can potentially cause message loss
            MessageBuilder.withPayload(result)
                .build()
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            channel.basicNack(deliveryTag, false, false)
            throw ex
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Consumer` to receive the message and `StreamBridge` to send (instead of using `Function`.

But why do you need manual acks anyway? Throwing the exception will cause the container to nack the message (and ack with normal exit) with auto mode.